# Error appears when I try to add an ON DELETE SET NULL, but not when I add an ON DELETE CASCADE in SQL (mysql server)

Tags: mysql

I tried to include an ON DELETE SET NULL constraint on a FOREIGN KEY, but the error 1215 appears.

```
    CREATE TABLE branch_supplier (
    -> branch_id INT,
    -> supplier_name VARCHAR(40),
    -> supply_type VARCHAR(40),
    -> PRIMARY KEY(branch_id, supplier_name),
    -> FOREIGN KEY(branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    -> );
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Otherwise, if I try to include a ON DELETE CASCADE constraint, the error doesn't appear. Does anyone know the reason why this happens?

```
    CREATE TABLE branch_supplier ( 
    -> branch_id INT,
    -> supplier_name VARCHAR(40), 
    -> supply_type VARCHAR(40), 
    -> PRIMARY KEY(branch_id, supplier_name), 
    -> FOREIGN KEY(branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE CASCADE 
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.26 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have `branch_id` field as a primary key and it doesn't allow `Null` value.

```
...
PRIMARY KEY(branch_id, supplier_name),
..
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't thought about it, but it is pretty obvious.